# RewriteRule htaccess с uploads/uploads на uploads/

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть ссылка типа:

```
http://домен//uploads//uploads/profile/photo-thumb-177264.jpeg
```

Нужно получить:

```
http://домен//uploads//profile/photo-thumb-177264.jpeg
```

Через *RewriteMod* в *htaccess*.

Как это сделать?

мой htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)(\?|$) - [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: а что такое *RewriteMod*?

Comment: Где есть и куда получить, напишите подробнее. При обращении по первой ссылке чтоб отдавался файл, который реально лежит по адресу второй ссылки?

Comment: @ toxxxa думаю, что наоборот, но хотелось бы услышать автора вопроса :)

Comment: При обращении к первой ссылке отдавалась вторая ссылка, кстати я сделал symlink в директории как временный фикс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
RewriteRule (.*)(uploads/uploads)(.*) $1uploads$3 [L]
```

сделает от

```
http://домен/uploads/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-177264.jpeg
```

это

```
http://домен/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-177264.jpeg
```

P.S. тут я еще подправил / вместо // если нужно было

Comment: Вылетает 500 ошибка. Мой htaccess добавил в вопрос

Comment: а куда вы добавили мой пример?

Comment: Перед RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: тогда понятно. тогда вам нужно поставить флаг [L] в конце этой строки. `RewriteRule (.*)(uploads/uploads)(.*) $1uploads$3 [L]`